# Compiler insisting an external parameter label is required when non is specified

Tags: swift

The compiler rejects this code snippet

```
func setCoordinate(theCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)  {
    class MapPin : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        init(x: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            self.coordinate = x
        }
    }

    let pin = MapPin(theCoordinate)
```

It says there is a label missing and the correct syntax should be:

```
let pin = MapPin(x: theCoordinate)
```

But the init method is not declaring an external parameter name so why is the compiler saying there is a problem? i.e. I thought the code had to be something like this to use an external label:

```
func setCoordinate(theCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)  {
    println("cheese \(theCoordinate.longitude) \(theCoordinate.latitude)")
    class MapPin : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        init(theExternalLabel theInternalName: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            self.coordinate = theInternalName
        }
    }

    let pin = MapPin(theExternalLabel: theCoordinate)
```

So why is the compiler insisting that in the first code snippet the x: label must be used when calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init methods have an external name for all parameters. This helps with swift's compatibility with cocoa. For most methods the first parameter name is part of the function name so it doesn't have an external name. Since init methods just use the class name for the function name, they have to show the external name somewhere.

For example, an objective-c init looks like this:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:nil length:0 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

In order to show that the first parameter is bytes in swift, it uses an external name.

```
NSString(bytes: nil, length: 0, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```